# What's the difference between "cabinet" and "cupboard"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

What's the difference between "cabinet" and "cupboard"?

Comment: In the UK you would place government ministers in a cabinet but not a cupboard. :)

Comment: I kind of expected this joke to show up here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A cupboard is a closed piece of furniture with one or more doors and possibly shelves. A cabinet is more like a closet, and might be built into a wall or a separate piece of furniture. Cabinets are typically considered general-purpose storage, while cupboards are more for food and dishes. The two are somewhat interchangeable, and you might say that a cupboard is a type of cabinet.

Comment: +1, in other words, a cupboard is a cabinet for kitchen-related use

Comment: Yeah, what he said.

Comment: Perhaps there are regional variations, as I'd say that a cupboard is the more general-purpose receptacle, whereas a cabinet is more specific (e.g. medicine cabinet).

Answer (score 11):

In British English, a cupboard can be what Americans would call a 'closet'.  See: [cupboards and closets](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2009/09/cupboards-and-closets.html).

Answer (score 1):

A cupboard would be a cabinet with shelving where you would place cups plates and bowls. Where as a cabinet would have shelves but would be used for other items and in a kitchen is usually located below the counter tops. Also a cabinet would be used in other places in a home besides the kitchen for storing other items.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU. Citing a reference to support your position would make this a better answer. Otherwise this can be seen as just your opinion, and The SE model is to give answers with some kind of authoritative reference. Since you're here, please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.