# Where in the world are cabinets called cupboards?

Tags: word-usage

I understand the difference between [cabinet and cupboard](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5415/whats-the-difference-between-cabinet-and-cupboard).

However, I have spent part of my life redoing houses and I have only ever heard of *kitchen cabinets*.  In fact if I order "cabinets" the stores and manufacturers refer to them as *kitchen cabinets*.

I do remember my grandparents using the term *cupboards* when younger but never hear it anymore in the US.  Is the term *cupboard* outdated?  I would like to know if it has any usage.

[This question stems from me traveling in Europe the past few weeks.  All non-native English speakers were taught *cupboards*.]

Just to give the most uncupboard type example.  Something like the picture below was called a *cupboard* in three different countries over the past week.  Trying to be really specific here.  I am wondering if this is an actual term used, or if it is a term from books that were outdated used to teach English.

[image: An ultra-modern kitchen with upper and lower cabinets, a peninsula, and a TV between two tall pantry cabinets. Everything in the kitchen is built-in, i.e. attached to the wall and not moveable.]

To add some of my background I went to the three biggest home improvement store sites (in the US) for some insight.

- [Lowes (Kitchen Cabinets)](http://www.lowes.com/Kitchen/Kitchen-Cabinets/_/N-1z0z390/pl)
- [Home depot (Cabinets)](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Kitchen-Cabinets-Cabinet-Hardware/N-5yc1vZas87)
- [Menard's (Kitchen Cabinets)](http://www.menards.com/main/kitchen/cabinets/c-12410.htm)

Comment: With kitchen units, you *buy* a cabinet. Once it's assembled and on the wall, it's a cupboard.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I have never heard of that and I am in the industry.  I buy cabinets, install cabinets, and after you enjoy your cabinets.

Comment: I learned it growing up around Los Angeles, back in the 50s-60s. It was a common term, real popular. Don't know now as I haven't lived there in 40+ years.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd We may be enjoying *your* cabinets, but they are *our* cupboards. Actually I think it's to do with size, and kitchen cupboards are borderline. A bathroom cupboard would contain towels; a bathroom cabinet contains toiletries.

Comment: 'I understand the difference between the two words and it was answered _here_.' I've just read the link, and think that the answers don't agree. The terms are doubtless used in overlapping ways, and differently in different regions (or even say antiques establishments). In the UK, I'd say that 'cabinet' is reserved for some specialist examples (bathroom cabinet) and valuable antiques (Louis XVIII cabinet). A sideboard will usually have 'cupboards', and almost all built-in examples will be 'cupboards'.

Comment: Agree with @EdwinAshworth's comments: the distinctions seem to vary by country.  From a Canadian perspective, cupboard is commonly used for built-in units for food or dishes; stand alone furniture is more likely to be a "china cabinet".  However, cupboard is about function while cabinet specifies form: "Do you want cabinets or open shelving?" (cabinet implies doors) or "Do you want wall cabinets or a pantry unit?" (pantry is full-height, possibly walk-in).  For that reason and because "cupboard" is somewhat informal, I'd expect "cabinet" to be used in store product descriptions.

Comment: @AmeliaBR - Interesting. We use both words in our house (midwestern US), but the freestanding units (like [this one](http://www.nadeausauction.com/auctiondata/1058/images/51_1.JPG)) are always cupboards, and never cabinets. The built-in units might get called by either name.

Comment: @J.R.  Interesting indeed.  That example is more rustic and utilitarian than what I picture as a [china cabinet](https://www.google.ca/search?q=china+cabinet&es_sm=93&tbm=isch) (note the glass doors on most of those images), so maybe local usage stems from that divide. The informal option, whatever that is most likely to be in a region, gets attached to "cupboard", while the more elegant version is a "cabinet".

Comment: And of course, if you continue your European travels out to the west and reach Ireland, you’re quite likely to hear kitchen cupboards (especially if it’s built into a recess in the wall, rather than ‘sticking out’ like the ones in your picture) referred to as a ***press***.

Comment: The first time I came to Ireland and someone told me that to get hot water for the shower, I had to turn on the doodad in the [hot press](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hot-press), I can assure you I was somewhat flummoxed, too. A press can be anything from a large-ish kitchen cupboard to an entire small room (a hot press is sometimes really what you’d think of as a boiler room with shelves for towels and linen and stuff).

Comment: I believed in the US, china cabinets as shown in the link above, were commonly referred to as [*hutches*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=china+cabinet&es_sm=93&tbm=isch#q=hutch&tbm=isch), whereas in the UK I've always called that piece of furniture a [*kitchen dresser*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=china+cabinet&es_sm=93&tbm=isch#q=kitchen+dresser&tbm=isch).

Comment: A cupboard is a perfectly normal thing. “Get a glass from the cupboard” is used for the things hanging in kitchens. Asking for one from a cabinet sounds like some free-standing hutch in the next room. @EdwinAshworth I agree with you about cabinets being something special, although I know that’s the term builders use, nobody else would call them that.

Comment: Harry Potter sleeps in the [cupboard under the stairs](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cupboard_Under_the_Stairs), so the word is still used in England. As an American, I would ***not*** call that a cabinet, since a cabinet should have shelves in it, which would make it difficult to get into, let alone sleep in. (Cupboards ***can*** have shelves, but don't need to.) I don't know whether this is British usage, as well.

Comment: I believe that Old Mother Hubbard's house did not contain any cabinets, whereas Dr. Caligari's laboratory lacked cupboards.

Comment: 1. Anything you can walk into cannot possibly be either a *cupboard* or a *cabinet*. Harry Potter used to sleep in a *closet* under the stairs. 2. Born and raised in California, and *cupboard* is one of those quaint words that you might meet in a British or Midwestern publication, but wouldn't ever use yourself. The storage units in the kitchen, as well as the tall piece of furniture with the glass doors in the dining room, are all *cabinets*.

Comment: @Martha. I also was born and raised in California, and I always called them _cupboards_ if in the kitchen and attached to the wall.  Anywhere else it would be a _cabinet_ and could be a _cabinet_ in the kitchen.  I grew up in Northern California, and my grandparents we're from MA, ND and southern CA.  Admittedly, _cabinet_ seemed the more formal term.  To me these distinctions seem similar to _washcloth_ and _washrag_, which I consider mostly interchangeable, though the latter I would use mostly and consider less formal.

Comment: Even The Wolf and the Seven Kids uses cupboard.  "The fifth (kid sprang) into the cupboard."  http://germanstories.vcu.edu/grimm/wolf_e.html   Often old names are still used even if the shape of the thing has changed.

Answer (score 9):

Where in the world are cabinets more often referred to as cupboards? In the world of ESL (English as a second language).

I teach English to private students in my spare time and in all the textbooks I have in my possession, be it for nursery school children or adults who are taking advanced level exams, the piece of furniture that the OP refers to as cabinet, is rarely mentioned. In fact, I don't think I've ever seen the word cabinet in any ESL textbook.

Instead, it's *[cupboards](https://www.google.ca/search?q=kitchen+cupboards+uk&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=5K1mU7qJLoeEyAPaxIDYCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=653)* (unless it's a *trophy cabinet*); *[wardrobes](https://www.google.ca/search?q=china%20cabinet&es_sm=93&tbm=isch#q=wardrobes%20uk&tbm=isch)* (never *closets*); [sofas](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sofas%20uk&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=mK1mU_fdBIaS7Qb6xoGoDg&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=653) (never *couches*); and bedroom or [kitchen dressers](https://www.google.ca/search?q=china%20cabinet&es_sm=93&tbm=isch#q=kitchen%20dressers%20uk&tbm=isch) (never *hutches*) etc. This might well explain why the non-native speakers in Europe were all familiar with the term *cupboard* but not with *cabinet*.

**Edit 1**
And I confirm @Dan Sheppard's statement that the above linked terms are standard British English terms.

---

**Edit 2**

I scanned this page from an English coursebook with its accompanying picture. It's taken from *Elementary New Headway English Course* by Liz and John Soars; published by Oxford University Press. This edition is dated 2000

[image: "What's in the Kitchen" page from an ESL textbook. There's a picture of a man and a woman standing in a standard western kitchen, complete with range, range hood, and butcher-block kitchen table/island. The conversation includes the lines "Well, it's not very big, but there ___ a ___ of cupboards." and "But what's *in* all these cupboards?"]

> **Headway** was first published in 1986 as a two-level course and its
>   integrated syllabus, explicit grammar rules and user-friendliness made
>   it work equally well in the hands of both experienced and novice
>   teachers.  Now in its fourth edition, its continuing popularity has
>   resulted in 70 million copies sold and it is estimated that [more than
>   100 million students](http://ihjournal.com/an-interview-with-liz-and-john-soars-2) in secondary schools, tertiary and teacher
>   training institutions **in 127 countries** have learned English using the
>   course.

---

**Edit 3**

Not all kitchen cupboards in the UK or for that matter in ESL textbooks are like the ones shown in the image above. There is another type of cupboard, the tall freestanding unit containing shelves complete with one or more doors. In *New English File Elementary* by Oxford University Press, 2008, there is an exercise where you have to match the words with the pictures.

[image: A page from a textbook showing a cutaway view of an apartment. Various objects are labeled with numbers, and the numbers are explained in a list on the left. Item 12 is a tall narrow cabinet with legs, a single large door, and one drawer at the bottom. The key for item 12 says "a cupboard /'kʌbəd/".]

Take note that AmEng terms such as; *stove/range*, *faucet*, *couch/loveseat*, and *cabinets=cupboards*, are rarely found in British English coursebooks nor taught to learners. In my experience Italians tend to be taught English by non-native speakers who were themselves taught exclusively in British English. The ubiquitous AmEng terms such as: *candy*, *cookies*, *(french) fries*, *soccer*, *elevator*,  and *truck*, might be taught alongside *sweets*, *biscuits*, *chips*, *football*, *lift* and *lorry* but strangely enough, AmEng named furniture is normally excluded and I don't really know why.  Generally speaking, the teaching of furniture vocabulary is relegated at elementary levels and rarely revised or expanded at higher levels.

Comment: All of these ESL usages are also the standard usages in British English.

Comment: Kitchens can’t have dressers, since one never puts garments in a kitchen cupboard; one places cups there.  Plus a dresser starts from the ground and goes up. Sometimes cupboards do that, but often then start from the ceiling and go down.

Comment: http://thekitchendresser.co.uk/furniture/kitchen-dressers/, the links are all Google images. I was pointing out that the term, hutches, is very unusual in BrEng. Yes, you have bedroom dressers where you put garments but also kitchen ones for cups, plates, cutlery (flatware) etc.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: I think I've worked out you're British but living in Italy. As you also teach, you won't have gone round many National Trust properties – you don't have the time. The term 'cabinet' (when not handcuffed to 'bathroom' or 'display') has a cachet that 'cupboard' usually doesn't have, so anything worth over say 10 000 sterling automatically seems to become a cabinet. To confuse the issue, antique experts argue over whether 'court cupboards' are allowed to have any enclosed compartments.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am quite familiar with glass cabinets that display chinaware or crockery (is there a difference?) and with antique cabinets from France, Italy and the UK. When I mention *trophy cabinets* it was referring to instances found in ESL/EFL textbooks. Personally, I find it very disappointing that many American expressions that differ from BrEng (*candy*, *sidewalk*, *closet* etc.) are absent. Young students love learning these terms, because they hear them all the time in AmEng pop/hip-hop songs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth as a favour, could you tell me if I misinterpreted tchrist's earlier comment? Is he saying that (kitchen) dressers do not belong in the kitchen?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - This is really good insight.  I don't care what they are called.  I just have done a lot of work in the industry and have never heard of them referred to as cupboards anywhere in the US.  When someone says cupboard to me I think of something old/wooden or something that looks like a hutch.  I didn't know it was carried over for modern kitchen "cabinets".  All of the people I spoke to learned English through their work.  Where they would have English classes as part of their work routine until they hit a certain level (finance fields).

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Your answer is fine. I could say 'Kitchens can't have hutches, since one never keeps rabbits in the kitchen', but that would be being dismissive of someone else's usages. 'Welsh dresser', 'kitchen dresser' or the shortened form 'dresser' are the [correct terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_dresser) in the UK at least for certain types of open china-display case pieces. (The US and UK usages of the terms 'credenza' and 'girandole' don't match either, and 'buffet' and 'commode' have very different accepted senses even within the UK.) (Retired: got time to visit NT properties:-)

Comment: @Edwin, your pseudo-sarcastic rabbit remark was actually exactly what went through my mind when I read the third paragraph of this answer. I have never heard of a _hutch_ being something in the kitchen in my life (even from Americans)! On the rare occasion that I’ve heard that word used at all, it’s been the little wiry rabbit containers; and the kitchen thing I’ve only ever heard called a dresser (or even just a cupboard by people who know about as much about furniture nomenclature as me).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I posted a link under Ryebread's question, showing that *hutch* is AmEng for Welsh/kitchen dresser-tsk! :) Edwin's link is better than mine, though.

Comment: I think I have to call [this beast](http://www.mrbeasleys.com/store/cart.php?m=product_detail&p=2997) a 'buffet and hutch' rather than a dresser.

Comment: @Janus A pseudo-sarcastic rabbit remark? I only remember one: 'Say, What's up, Doc?'

Comment: This answer appears to be off-topic as it's a thinly veiled attempt to sell us all a new kitchen. Or a few cupboards. Or some fake verbenas. Or a set of _Headway English_. Or a pseudo-sarcastic rabbit.

Comment: I've always thought that cupboards were for showing off things in a beautiful piece of furniture. A display piece. Cabinets were things you didn't want to show off and to hide your things. If you have fine China, you'd put it in your cupboard in your living room. You'd put your regular used plates in the kitchen cabinets.

Comment: I also teach English, and I'd like to add 'almirah' to the list. It's an Indian-English word for a free standing wardrobe/cupboard. It even has its own definition here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/almirah

Answer (score 3):

If you type 'buy cupboard' into google, you will find a very large number of results with the .co.uk suffix. You will find cupboard in use anywhere British English is the dominant form of English. This statement is supported by the answers of @Ronan and @user3217790 who confirm its usage in Ireland and Australia respectively, where British English is spoken, not American.

Answer (score 2):

In Ireland, especially among the older generation, where these cabinets actually were used to hold cups, they're called cupboards. A quick [Google.ie](https://www.google.ie/search?q=cupboards) search for "cupboards" results in a range of listings for furniture retailers selling "cupboards" rather than "cabinets", although "press" is probably the most common term for these.

The popular Paddywhackery website [Irish Central](http://www.irishcentral.com/culture/craic/top-ten-words-the-irish-use-that-never-fail-to-confuse-americans-167418095-237788081.html) also uses "cupboard" listed in its *Top Ten words the Irish use that confuse Americans* as a means of explaining what a "Hotpress" is. Although I think the use of cupboard may just confuse the Americans further.

> Hotpress
>
> Again, this seems totally logical to the Irish mind. The hotpress is
>   the airing cupboard where you might store sheets and towels, located
>   next to the boiler. So therefore it is a press (cupboard) which is
>   hot.

Comment: "press" is also used in the north-east of England, by my 80 year old mother, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Australia - cupboard is far more commonly used, especially when referring to one that is built in to a house, rather than free standing.