# From ‘cupboard’, a chair is taken out?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, historical-change, transatlantic-differences

It seems to me that ‘cupboard’ in the 21st century is usually a closet or cabinet; a piece of furniture usually with shelves for storing food, crockery, and utensils. But early in the 20th century, ‘cupboard’ was in most cases a recess with a door and shelves for storage of not only of cups and saucers, but also daily things such as a small chair. Now isn’t this called a ‘storage room’?

If I am right in my definition of this word, in what decades of the 20th century did this change or transition of lexical meaning occurred?

I was much surprised to find the unfamiliar usage of 'cupboard' in these stage directions, which are from *Belinda*, a play written by A. A. Milne in 1922.

- (*Takes up a vase from a chair in cupboard arid shakes it as if draining it.*)
- Baxter (*meeting Belinda coming out of the cupboard*)
- Belinda (*bundling him into the cupboard and closing the door*). Hush.

Comment: [Which side of the Atlantic](https://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/ar-clo1.htm) are you thinking of? :)  Cabinets, closets, cupboards, pantries, dressers, chests-of-drawers, chiffarobes, armoires, wardrobes, aumbries, almirahs, muurkas &c can mean **quite** different things on [one side of North Atlantic](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5415) than [on the other](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/167914). And that isn’t even taking the Southern Hemisphere into account, or the Subcontinent, some of which have their own traditions.

Comment: You may be thinking of a pantry, which is a closet especially for food storage. I don’t know why one would keep a chair in such a space unless one needed it to reach upper shelves.

Comment: As an AmE speaker from the mid to late 20th c, your first definition is mine. Where did you hear that a cupboard could  hold an entire chair? Could you give a quote or reference? I've never heard that before.

Comment: I have seen large cupboards that hold stacks of chairs.

Comment: @Peter But do you mean a wall-mounted cabinet or a walk-in closet?

Comment: @tchrist, I mean a cupboard that is built into the structure of the building (and appears in the plans). A human could walk/crouch into the space left by a chair stack after it was wheeled out on a trolley, but you could not enter the cupboard when it was filled to its designed capacity.

Comment: @tchrist, to me (in Australia) "walk-in" implies the existence of space that is meant to allow access to the stored items, so a person can enter when it is full. A cupboard does not have this space; when it is full there is no room to enter it.

Comment: I believe 4 Privet Drive has a cupboard under the stairs that’s large enough to sleep in.

Comment: Yes, in a meeting room or dining room, There is often a built-in storage closet for items like folding chairs, coffee urns and whatnot. These are often not full height, being crammed under stairs or equipment spaces. I think cupboard is idiomatic for such spaces where the same thing in a different room might be called a closet.

Comment: @tchrist a *cupboard under the stairs* (is this term used outside the UK?) is neither wall-mounted nor necessarily walk-in.  Mine could be described as crawl-in, and with careful stacking and less junk could take all my dining chairs

Comment: @ChrisH That's a closet.

Comment: @tchrist when "closet" is (rarely) used in British English, IME it's always big enough to stand up in.  A standing-height cupboard under the stairs wouldn't be called a closet at leats in Southern England; room names are quite variable within the UK.

Comment: ...and note that the original context was AA Milne, from my part of the world

Comment: @tchrist, I cannot imagine the space under the stairs being called anything other than a cupboard in British English.  I live in a bungalow with no stairs, and we still have a space which we call "cupboard under the stairs" because it is where we keep the vacuum cleaner, ironing board and spare chairs.  I guess closet might be no longer used because of the awkward connection to the phrase "in the closet".

Comment: @ChrisH The proper architectural term for the triangular space under the stairs is a [**spandrel**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spandrel) (definition 3). In my AmE dialect, an enclosed storage space in a stair spandrel would be a "closet". My first mental image of the phrase "cupboard under the stairs" is a set of built-in drawers and/or shelves.

Comment: For a related question, when did _cupboard_ become something other that a board on which cups were stored?

Comment: @CanadianYankee, an interesting term, but one that's never used in normal language, at least here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In British English, a cupboard can be either a free-standing piece of furniture or built-in. The one referred to by Milne is obviously a walk-in cupboard, which presumably must have been mentioned somewhere in the stage directions. The date of the play is not relevant; there has been no 'change in meaning'.

Comment: Is this the most common term for such? I'm used to using 'wardrobe' for a free standing piece of furniture mainly for clothes. British/Canadian English, although for this particular word I'm relying on my Br. English side.

Comment: @AlanMunn bedrooms have wardrobes, but other rooms often have cupboards, kitchen ones usually being attached to the walls.

Answer (score 3):

In Australian English the generic term would be "storage space", not "storage room".

A storage room is a room, i.e. an inside space which is large enough to walk around in and used for storage. A room may be small, for example a toilet.

A cupboard is different from a storage room because it is not intended to be occupied. A built-in cupboard may have the same floor as the house and appear on house plans to be similar to a very small room, but it is not designed for occupancy and there is usually no light, ventilation or an interior door handle. Access to such a cupboard is usually through a person standing in its doorway. Other built-in cupboards, such as those built under a bench, cannot be entered easily.

Some cupboards are free-standing units, used for storage. If such a cupboard were large enough, it could contain a chair or a person. The word is also used for the closable part of a storage unit, built-in or free-standing, which is partly closable and partly open.

Some words may refer to cupboards or to other spaces. A pantry may be a cupboard, but in some older houses it is a room containing food storage cupboards. In a caravan it may be a shelf. Some modern houses have a "walk-in pantry", which has shelves and enough floor space to allow access to the shelves. Such a pantry would not be referred to as a cupboard. Similarly a "walk-in-robe" serves the function of a wardrobe for storing clothes, but allows access for a person within the space. The clothes themselves may be on open spaces or closed spaces (cupboards) within the "walk-in-robe".

In my experience, the essential features of a cupboard are that it is intended for storage, closable with a door, and not designed to be occupied.

Comment: What you describe in your second paragraph is invariably a *closet* here.

Comment: “Some modern houses have a ‘walk-in pantry’ […] Such a pantry would not be referred to as a cupboard.”  I know people in both Australia and the UK who have such pantries and call them cupboards.

Comment: @PLL, fair enough. I haven't come across the usage though; people I know call them pantries.