# What are the differences between the storage things?

Tags: differences

What are differences between the words *wardrobe, cupboard, closet, drawer, cabinet*, and other terms used for objects in which things are stored? (I can't think of other terms right now.)

For me *wardrobe* is only for the storage for clothes.  *Cupboard* is for the storage of anything.  *Closet* is more like part of room or a small room. *Drawer* and cabinet are similar; *cabinet* has drawer(s) and/or some other openings, and *drawer* for me is a single pull-open storage place.

Comment: Three of these are addressed at [What's the difference between "cabinet" and "cupboard"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5415/whats-the-difference-between-cabinet-and-cupboard). But there is no research presented here, and there are too many terms to explore. // From my days spent looking at antique furniture in references by eg Miller, the terms are often confusingly overlapping, and not standardised.

Comment: @bill If my edit changes the meaning of your Question, just change it back.  In particular, I may have misunderstood your distinction between cabinet and drawer.

Comment: @ab2 drawer with only pull-open storage place and cabinet may be with only drawer or including drawer and mixed with wardrobe kind of pull-open.Anyway could you please throw light on how differenct are they from each other?Thanks.

Comment: @bill a cabinet can (but does not have to) have both shelves and drawers.   David Blomstrom's answer is good.  I disagree only with his saying that cupboards are in kitchens and cabinets are in living rooms.  I refer to my kitchen cabinets -- not because they are fine pieces -- but because where I come from, cabinet is used as a word much more often than cupboard.

Comment: This is in large part dependent on your family heritage and culture.  What one family calls a wardrobe may be a cupboard or closet to another family.